# visual c# WPF: create settings window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, settings

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I'm developing a project with C# and WPF.
In my application I need to have a simple settings window, as you can see in every Windows application. So, I create a new page with a treeview on the left and a frame on the center. When I click on a treeview item, the content of the frame changes. If I select a checkbox present in page1, then I select second treeview item, when I return back to first the checkbox loses his selection. I need that values are maintained and, if I click OK button, values are stored in a xml file (I just know how to write to an XML file).
Do you know any samples about this kind of development?

Thanks for your help

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instances of each page at setting page creation time

```
Page1 page1 = new Page1();
```

and then switch between them like this:

```
internal static void LoadPage(string pageName)
{
    string currentPage = "";
    if (Main_Content.Content != null)
    {
        var page = Main_Content.Content as Page;
        if (page != null)
            currentPage = page.Name ?? "";
    }

    if (currentPage != pageName)
    {
        switch (pageName)
        {
            case "page1":                   
                Main_Content.Content = page1;
                break;      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As described in my post, I select treeview nodes to change frame content. I change content using this.frame.Source = new Uri("uri"); but in this way I cannot "temporary" selections done in the pages. If I use this.frame.Content = new Page1(); nothing changes...I hope you understand my problem

Comment: I understand your problem but you don't understand my answer. You should create the instances on Load event of the Page/Window containing treeview component. Then you don't set content to `new Page1();` bu to local variable `page1`

Comment: I've done this...but result is the same...i need something that updates the local variable...but how to refer to the variable to update it?

Comment: It works for me. If you want here is example project I've created for you [link](http://www.theoutsourcing.pl/WpfApplication1.zip)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is about content assignment (I've used URI and it is not needed...)